# Testing of text files which will be held on a web server

Tags: c#, winforms, http, iis-7, webrequest

I need to read the values in a standard .txt file that will be held on a web-server.
I have written the code to use a WebRequest to read the file contents line by line.

I know where the files are going to be stored, but they won't be there for a while yet. URL will be in the following format:
http://sitename.co.uk/Folder/Values.txt

Is there a way I can setup a local folder in IIS and then use this in my WinForm application to test the code? This will allow for testing before moving into the live environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand something but can you just mirror your production environment in your testing environment and hit the testing URL? Or create a testing instance of IIS and use your WinForm app to test?

Comment: What have you tried? You can always use your local IIS to create such a site, and then modify hosts file to mock the target domain name.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the local domain name for test on your machine then you need to add that domain name in hostile.

You could implement your requirement by following below steps:

1)Create site in iis

2)Use site binding as below:

type:HTTP

IP address: your machine IP address

port: 80

Hostname: as your requirement (e.g sample.com)

3)Now open hosts in notepad as administrator. open "hosts" file which is located at "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"

here you have to add an entry consisting of your local IP address and the domain name. For example, if your IP address on your machine was 192.168.1.10 then you would add:

192.168.1.10 [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com)

[image]

save the file and restart the site in iis then browse the site.